# prove that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin \frac{1}{x}}{x^{\frac{3}{2}} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)} \mathrm{d} x $ is convergent

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence

prove that $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin \frac{1}{x}}{x^{\frac{3}{2}} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)} \mathrm{d} x $$ is convergent
. I try to transform it into $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\frac{1}{x}\sin \frac{1}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{2}} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)} \mathrm{d} x $ and use Abel's test but failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $1$ is not an improper bound of this integral.

Then, use the substitution you suggested ($u=\frac{1}{x}$) an finally try to prove that the new integrand $f=o_{+\infty}(\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}})$ for $\alpha>1$, therefore integrable in $[1;+\infty]$.

Comment: thanks, after the substitution, note that $| \sin x|<1 \> \text{while} \> \left | \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)} \right | $ is monotonically decreasing, by comparison test, we could prove it. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^{3/2}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\, {\rm d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{-1}\cdot x^{-1/2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\, {\rm d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^{1/2}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\, {\rm d}x.$$
Via change of variables $u(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ so $u'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\downarrow 0}u(x)=+\infty$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1}u(x)=1$, then $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^{1/2}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\, {\rm d}x=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{u^{1/2}\ln(1+u)}\, {\rm d}u.$$
Now define the following maps

- $f: [1,+\infty[\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ by $\displaystyle x\longmapsto \frac{1}{x^{1/2}\ln(1+x)}$ and notice that $f$ monotonically decreasing and non-negative function.

See here

[image]

- $g: [1,+\infty[ \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ by $\displaystyle x\longmapsto \sin(x)$ and notice that $g$ uniformly bounded by $2$.

See here

[image]

Hence by  [Dirichlet's test for improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals) we ensure the convergence of $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{u^{1/2}\ln(1+u)}\times \sin(u)\, {\rm d}u$ and therefore the convergence of   $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^{3/2}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\, {\rm d}x$.